# To Discord.js master

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, discord.js

i got an error. PLZ HELP ME!!
I tried the slash command bot.
And i have been getting this error.
I have tried hard to solve this error.
I gave the bot full permission.
So, I don't know what to do, so I ask here.

Error content: https://pastebin.com/G0CH6QBK

````
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: 405: Method Not Allowed
    at RequestHandler.execute (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/CM/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/CM/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager.set (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/CM/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager.js:186:18)
    at async /data/data/com.termux/files/home/CM/Handlers/Commands.js:60:5 {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/applications/971797595313827931/guilds/951450095658872853/commands/permissions',
  code: 0,
  httpStatus: 405,
  requestData: {
    json: [
      {
        id: '972066482475393044',
        permissions: [
          { id: '951450095658872853', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '951469564242321419', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '951497606733918221', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '951504382413926450', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '952860149054312499', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '959619628022259735', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '961465754526576652', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971431284519870555', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971431411804409917', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971432006678376539', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971432790254030868', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971435796450140241', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971443167545163886', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971444177873285130', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971516546834890814', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971690107688083522', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971952762319421470', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '971953522901909524', permission: true, type: 1 },
          { id: '972066442621120556', permission: true, type: 1 }
        ]
      }
    ],
    files: []
  }
}```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the future, please provide your code. It is obviously incredibly difficult to solve issues with your code, if you don't even show us a line of your code.

Second, this issue has nothing to do with discord.js or code, hence why I'm able to answer your question without being provided any of your code. The issue is that Discord recently updated its slash command permissions system across all applicable versions of the API. They removed the HTTP endpoint to bulk-update permissions for all slash commands at once, and phased out bots' ability to control command permissions. Command permissions can now only be controlled by users/ Hence, `ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager.set()` will not work for you anymore.

You have two options. If you want to use the actual permissions system, you can authenticate with the admin user and control command permissions through them. The second option is to not use the permissions system, and instead manually check permissions with your bot on command use (though this will not show commands as disabled to users who do not have perms to use the command).

See the updated [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#permissions) for the permissions system.

Ignore the snippet of code that was previously included with this answer, as I misinterpreted the announcement about the changes made to the permissions system. The answer to your question is: it's not possible.

Comment: Bots no longer control permissions, in any way. The closest programmatic way is using a Bearer token and doing it on a user's behalf

Comment: That is correct, I misinterpreted Discord's announcement about the change. I've edited the answer to reflect this. However, I am curious: is it now possible to define more complex default permissions when creating the command? In the [docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-command-object), there's a new `default_member_permissions` field. Could that be used as an alternative to bots directly managing the permissions?